# Scrape paragraphs in html with anchor links in Puppeteer

Tags: puppeteer

I am trying to scrape a text on a website with puppeteer. Now I have reached the point where I can read the p-tag between two h2-tags, only this paragraph texts also contain words with internal links. With the current code I get the plain paragraph texts in an array as ouput but actually I need to have the text with the `<a href="#"> </a>` tags in it. Is this possible with puppeteer?

My current code for paragraph scrape is:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');


const plaatsengids = async () => {

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const [page] = await browser.pages();

    await page.goto('https://www.plaatsengids.nl/urmond');

    let paragraphs = await page.evaluate(() => {
      const status = document.querySelector('h2[name="status"]');
      const naam = document.querySelector('h2[name="naam"]');

      return [...document.querySelectorAll('p')]
        .filter(p => p.compareDocumentPosition(status) & Node.DOCUMENT_POSITION_PRECEDING &&
                     p.compareDocumentPosition(naam) & Node.DOCUMENT_POSITION_FOLLOWING)
        .map(p => p.textContent.replace("- ",""));
    });

    console.log(paragraphs);

    await browser.close();

    return paragraphs;

};

module.exports = plaatsengids;
```

The page I am trying to scrape is:
https://www.plaatsengids.nl/urmond

For example, the words that contain an a-tag in the text are circled in red here:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can try `p.innerHTML.replace("- ","")` instead of `p.textContent.replace("- ","")`.